# Reference request: Book on theory of rank of matrices and multi-linear operators!

Tags: reference-request, matrix-rank, multilinear-algebra, tensor-rank

Is there a reference out there that only focus on (different)rank of matrices(with all kind of entries: real, complex, integers) and connects then further to ranks of tensors and further with the ranks multi-linear operators.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you say a bit more about what it is you want to learn about? You can obtain the rank of a matrix by putting it into a standard form like reduced row echelon form. You can also study the space of matrices of a given rank $r$, by using determinants of minors, by the action the groups of change-of-basis matrices etc.. What do you want to use ranks to study for example?